How to decompile Java class with correct line numbers in Visual Studio Code?
I am using vscode version 1.92.2 in macOS with Extension Pack for Java v0.29.0. When I command + click or right click -> Go to definition of a class that I do not have source code, vscode opens the .class file using FernFlower decompiler. However it does not maintain the original line numbers. This is for IntelliJ. How to do the same for vscode?
The reason why I require the original line numbers as I can navigate to exact line that threw exception from stack trace.
FYI, I have checked with external decompiler where it shows correct line numbers, means the classes or jar files still have the debug information.

In general you can't since all the white space and comment lines will have been stripped from the executable code (unless the original has extra debugging info embedded in it)..

@MartinBrown I have checked with external decompiler where it shows correct line numbers, means the class or jar still have the debug information.

@LeeCheeKiam people tend to down vote questions that are more suitable to be discussed elsewhere, and in your case the extension's GitHub repo is a better place. The IntelliJ one can be moved to IntelliJ issue tracker as well, but it might be lucky to remain on this site.

Hello, is it possible to get the desired effect with the RedHat Java extension?

@LexLi, thanks for your explanation. Based on Stack Overflow general guideline, seems this question belongs to 'software tools commonly used by programmers'. Does Stack Overflow has a way to find out reasons of down vote?

Hello, the RedHat Java extension integrates the built-in Fernflower decompiler, maybe you can give it a try.

HI, I’ve did some research on the plugin built-in Fernflower Decompiler and it does not maintain the line of code. This was opened 4 years ago but there hasn’t been too much progress towards it. You may check it here:
Add a decompiler to the pack · Issue #18 · microsoft/vscode-java-pack · GitHub
You may try to set a 3rd party decompiler in the redhat.java plugin settings and see if this could help.

After conducting a thorough search, I have discovered an open issue regarding the implementation of a Java decompiler in Visual Studio Code, which can be found at https://github.com/dgileadi/vscode-java-decompiler/issues/4.
It appears that this functionality has not been implemented as of yet. Therefore, you have two options: either wait patiently for the implementation to be completed, or take the initiative to implement it yourself.
